# Questions about Dunn's test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bonferroni, dunn-test

1. Authors in a paper state that they use the 'Bonferroni-Dunn test' as a post-hoc test. Is the 'Bonferroni-Dunn test' just a Dunn's test with Bonferroni adjustment or is it a different test (after searching on the internet I would say the former but who knows)?
2. Can Dunn's test also be used for paired samples (ignoring the fact that pairs have a an $\alpha$ value of 1)?

Comment: It might help if you could edit the question to provide a link to the paper you refer to. Sometimes the full context of the paper and details of the Methods section help to explain what authors meant by a particular phrase.

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by "pairs have an $\alpha$ value of 1." Paired tests, e.g. the paired *t* test, the signed-rank test, etc. conventionally use values of $\alpha=0.05$, $\alpha = 0.01$, etc. based on researcher preference for Type I  error.

Comment: @Alexis type from my side. i meant p value

Comment: The *p*-values of paired tests are not necessarily 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the paper it is a little unclear, but here's some possibilities:

1. **It may be that "Bonferroni-Dunn test" means a Bonferroni adjustment for multiple comparisons made to the application of Dunn's test.**
   Dunn's test is a *post hoc* pairwise comparisons test to be used after one has rejected the Kruskal-Wallis omnibus null hypothesis ($\text{H}_0\text{: }Pr(X_i > X_j) = 0.5$ for $i,j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ and $i\ne j$, and where $k$ is the number of groups on one's data set). This test is like a pairwise rank sum test, but (1) using the ranks from the Kruskal-Wallis test when calculating the statistic for each pair being tested, and (2) using the variance estimated under the Kruskal-Wallis null (akin to the pooled variance estimate used in the *post hoc* pairwise *t* tests following rejection of the omnibus null hypothesis in a one-way ANOVA). Given that there can be up to $\frac{k^2 - k}{2}$ pairwise tests, this raises the multiple comparisons issue.
2. **It may be that "Bonferroni-Dunn test" means that multiple tests of some sort were performed, and Dunn's 'Bonferroni' method was used to adjust rejection decisions.** (E.g., *post hoc* *t* tests following rejection of an omnibus null from a one-way ANOVA.) Olive Jean Dunn came up with what we today call the "Bonferroni" adjustment for multiple comparisons in her 1961 paper.
3. **Dunn's 'Bonferroni' method can be used in a very broad array of multiple tests scenarios, including ones using paired tests.**
4. ***Dunn's test* is not appropriate for paired data**

**References**
Dunn, O. J. (1964). [Multiple Comparisons Using Rank Sums](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00401706.1964.10490181). *Technometrics*, 6(3), 241–252.

Dunn, O. J. (1961). [Multiple Comparisons Among Means](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01621459.1961.10482090?needAccess=true&role=button). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 56(293), 52–64.